# inserting multiple values into one row mySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, datadesign

[image: example]

How can i insert multiple values into one row?

My query

```sql
insert into table_RekamMedis values ('RM001', '1999-05-01', 'D01', 'Dr Zurmaini', 'S11', 'Tropicana', 'B01', 'Sulfa', '3dd1');
```

i cant insert two values into one row. is there another way to do it?

Comment: ' is there another way to do it?' - sql has no such ability insert into 2 rows..and explain why  you want to insert into 1.

Comment: how can i get the result like that?

Comment: You cannot store in that way, store as 2 rows and format when selecting in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignorant of the human language you use, so this is a guess.

You have two [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) in your system. One is `dokter`, the other is `script` (prescription).  Your requirement is to store zero or more `script`s for each `dokter`. That is, the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) between your entities is one-to-many.

In a relational database management system (SQL system) you do that with two tables, one per entity. Your `dokter` table will contain a unique identifier for each doctor, and the doctor's descriptive attributes.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dokter(
  dokter_id  BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nama       VARCHAR (100),
  kode       VARCHAR(10),
  /* others ... */
);
```

And you'll have a second table for script

```sql
CREATE TABLE script (
  script_id  BIGINT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  dokter_id  BIGINT  NOT NULL,
  kode       VARCHAR(10),
  nama       VARCHAR(100),
  dosis      VARCHAR(100),
  /* others ... */
);
```

Then, when a doctor writes two prescriptions, you insert one row in `dokter` and two rows in `script`. You make the relationship between `script` and `dokter` by putting the correct `dokter_id` into each `script` row.

Then you can retrieve this information with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT dokter.dokter_id, dokter.nama, dokter.kode,
       script.script_id, script.kode, script.nama, script.dosis
  FROM dokter
  LEFT JOIN script ON dokter.dokter_id = script.dokter_id
```

Study up on [entity-relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) data design. It's worth your time to learn and will enhance your career immeasurably.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *store* multiple values in a single field but there are various options to achieve what you're looking for.

If you know that a given field can only have a set number of values then it *might* make sense to simply create multiple columns to hold these values. In your case, perhaps `Nama obat` only ever has 2 different values so you could break out that column into two columns: `Nama obat primary` and `Nama obat secondary`.

But if a given field could have any amount of values, then it would likely make sense to create a table to hold those values so that it looks something like:

| NoRM | NamaObat |
| --- | --- |
| RM001 | Sulfa |
| RM001 | Anymiem |
| RM001 | ABC |
| RM002 | XYZ |

And then you can combine that with your original table with a simple join:

```
SELECT * FROM table_RekamMedis JOIN table_NamaObat ON table_RekamMedis.NoRM = table_NamaObat.NoRM
```

The above takes care of storing the data. If you then want to query the data such that the results are presented in the way you laid out in your question, you could combine the multiple `NamaObat` fields into a single field using `GROUP_CONCAT` which could look something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NamaObat SEPARATOR '\n')
...
GROUP BY NoRM
```